# bot.event on_ready stops my commands from working discord.py

Tags: python, function, events, command, discord.py

I have programmed a background task which should send messages into the discord channel as soon as the bot is running. But now i have  a problem, my command is not working anymore i have tried to delete the `on_ready` function and then the command worked. But i need the `on_ready` and i don't know

My code:

```
import discord
from random import *
from time import *
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"PONG {bot.latency * 1000} ms")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    coins.start()

@tasks.loop(seconds=time())
async def coins():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))
    while True:
        time = randrange(120, 300)
        coins = randrange(100, 500)
        em = discord.Embed(title=f"COINSS!!", description=f"{coins} coins have spawned",color=0xf1c40f)
        await bot.get_guild(guild-id).get_channel(channel-id).send(embed=em)
        sleep(time)
```

Can you help?

Comment: Do you have an `on_message` event?

Comment: no i dont. i had one but it didnt work so i deleted it. i had the same problem with the on_message as i have now with my command. im not getting any errors either the bot just doesnt react

Comment: This problem usually occurs when you're using `on_message` event without processing commands.

Comment: You can try doing something like `print('Bot online')` after `coins.start()`. This will allow you to know if your bot is functioning after you started `coins`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with `time.sleep` used at the end of `coins`.

This is pause the whole bot for that amount. You should use `await asyncio.sleep(1)` so only the desired function will sleep.

Note: remember to `import asyncio`